# If Language $L_1$ is accepted by a Pushdown Automata and Language$ L_2$ by a Turing Machine, Is $L_1 \cup L_2$ accepted by a Pushdown Automata?

Tags: automata, turing-machines

Let $L_1$ be a language recognized by a Pushdown automaton and let $L_2$ be another language recognized by a Turing machine. Is  $L_1 \cup L_2$ recognized by a Pushdown automaton? Prove your answer.

Comment: What is your own attempt at answering the question? Where are you stuck? Also, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide on formatting your math.

Comment: I know that the Pushdown automata can accept languages like a^nb^n which can otherwise not be accepted by any finite state automata. I am also aware of the fact that Turing Machines are more powerful than both of these and may accept languages which the PDA cannot. HOwever I don't know which

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Suppose that $L_2$ is not recognizable by a pushdown automaton, and show that there is a regular $L_1\subseteq L_2$.